# Constructor Accessible Control in cpp

Tags: c++

We sometimes build an inherit system like:

`AbstractException` is the base class for some other class `DerivedException`.

But I don't want someone throw an `AbstractException` instance, because it means nothing actually.

I have know some methods to achieve it but some unavoidable shortcomings are a little unacceptable.

1. Using a pure virtual method to prevent the instantiation. But it's bad because I need to write a useless method implementation for the derived class.
2. Change the accessible levels of the constructor, for example change it to a protected constructor.

I prefer the second method. But I actually I have to write some codes like:

```cpp
struct BaseException : public std::runtime_error {
  protected: 
    // using std.... 
    BaseException(char const *): std::runtime_error("") {} 
    BaseException(std::string ): std::runtime_error("") {} 
}
```

Then I need to change the constructor again in the derived class definition.
It's quite inconvenient!

The `using` clauses cannot change the access level helpfully. Are there some better grammars for taking me out of this sea of misery?

Comment: Make the destructor protected instead. You can't create an instance of a class with inaccessible destructor.

Comment: Or a pure virtual destructor, if you want to be able to delete derived classes through a base class pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, so fantastic a solution! BTW, why I do not need to redeclare it as public in the derived class but I can create it? (I use 'using clause' to inherit the constructors. )

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Just now I try it, then an error in ld:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

BaseException::~BaseException() referenced from: 
DerivedException::~DerivedException() in test-....o

linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: I forgot to say, you also need to define the destructor (outside of the class body, pure virtual functions can't be defined inside).

Comment: A class that doesn't explicitly declare a destructor gets an implicitly declared one, which is public. If that's what you are asking.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, I get it. It's a wonderful solution.